# Redundancy on a CD

Tags: backup

I'd like to store data on a CD-R (using ISO-9660 filesystem). The data has only few megabytes, but the CD can store 700MB. Since I wouldn't be able to store more data on it after I finalize it (and I don't really want to put any more data on it) I figured out that I should utilize this free space.

I'd like to fill this CD up with copies of said data to have redundancy in case of damage of the data.

I have several questions:

1. Does this even make sense? Will this help to preserve the data?
2. How can I do it?
3. Is there a (preferably free) tool that would be capable of making this redundancy?

I guess a way to do this is to make many copies of the data and put them all to the ISO-9660 and then burn it. This is cumbersome but doable.

I think this approach isn't very robust. I can't imagine recovering the data from a damaged CD with this. There are no checksums, no extra protections, no nothing. I could make the checksums myself but I'm looking for a more complete solution.

I'm looking for any solution of this problem, but I would prefer something Linux compatible.

Comment: Why go to all the trouble for the price of a CD? Redundancy in backup strategy is to not put all your eggs in one basket. Burn 2 CDs, keep one at home, give one to a trusted friend. Put a copy on dropbox etc.

Comment: 3-2-1 rule: There should be 3 copies of data
    On 2 different media
    With 1 copy being off-site

Comment: If the primary volume descriptor is damaged, you won't be able to read any data from the CD. It is too much hassle for the reward. As others point it out, make a 3-2-1 backup instead.

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cds-truth-cddvd-longevity-mold-rot/ & 
https://www.clir.org/pubs/reports/pub121/sec5/ CD-R isn't really a reliable long term backup solution

Comment: There is/was a tool named dvdisaster which can do what you want. Unfortunately its project page seem to no longer exist. It was IIRC an open source software may be some code releases are still available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

CDs do have checksums – in "Mode 2", each 2352-byte sector stores 288 bytes of ECC data for every 2048 bytes of user data, allowing some read errors to be detected and sometimes fixed automatically.

Additionally, most popular archive formats include at the very least a CRC32 of each compressed file, allowing errors to be detected during file extraction. So even if the files aren't necessarily *compressible,* it can still be useful to pack them into a RAR/Zip/7z archive.

Some archive formats also support including additional "parity" or "error correction" data, such as RAR archives (if you enable "Recovery Record" in WinRAR) or the [PAR2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) format which is specifically meant for that purpose.

Finally, nothing stops you from manually including a text-file containing a list of hashes for every file, like the "sha256sums" or "md5sums" files that you sometimes see next to Linux ISOs.

Comment: Checksums are definitely useful, but their benefits are limited. I can't recreate large portions of the data with only a checksum. Using archive programs for error detection is definitely interesting. It wouldn't occur to me that they could be used in such a way. As I said, the size of the data is way less than the capacity of the CD, so I don't care if the parity data would be huge. I'll think this through.